# Angular: Do functions on components execute for each instance of the component?

Tags: angular, components, angular-components, angular-template

I have a component in my Angular app whose template includes two additional instances of the same component, like this (in template for `component1`):

```
<div>
  <...other tags...>
  <component1></component1>
  <component1></component1>
</div>
```

`component1` has a function that gets triggered on (mouseover). However, when I mouse over the outer `component1` and *not* over either of the nested instances of `component1`, the function gets triggered three times.

Does a function like this get triggered for all existing instances of the component?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on how you are triggering the function.

```html
<div>
  <hello></hello>
  <hello (mouseover)="func()"></hello>
</div>
```

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  func() {
    alert("hovered")
  }
}
```

This is called once only when you put the mouse over the right component. Here you can find how I reproduced it on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zqcvgd)